# Find a group of top feed backs from given set of input feedback

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp, sentiment-analysis

I am very new to the field of Natural language processing. My only experience was to use the standford nlp to get the part of speech for sentence.

Problem: I have to find out top 10 suggestions given in a set of product feedbacks.

Input: It consists of around one hundred feedbacks given as suggestions for some product.

I am not able to figure out where should I start the work from. On what basis should I create the top 10 suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

when you say you have a set of feedbacks, if there is any separator string or something involved then you can use regular expressions to separate the different feedbacks..
you can refer to this links for that

https://sites.google.com/site/gothnlp/links/regular-expressions

http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

If the separators are like the name of person submitting the feedback then you can look at the concept called named entity recognition which can separate person names.

If you can use the NLTk toolkit then I suugest you to use that..

http://www.slideshare.net/japerk/nltk-in-20-minutes

here is the link which can help

Also this blog might help you

http://blog.kaggle.com/2012/09/26/impermium-andreas-blog/

Comment: thanks for your response @Gunjan. Actualy i was not looking for this. I want to get the group of top suggestions given from a set of feedback.

Comment: by top suggestion u mean the better oncs?

Comment: yes..from group of feedback(that has been given as suggestion) , need to pick up the top suggestions..say top 10